# Constraint: Only one row must have a NULL value

Tags: postgresql

Only one row is allowed to have parent_id NULL:

```
CREATE TABLE simple21_page (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(120) NOT NULL,
    text text NOT NULL,
    parent_id integer
);
```

This is a tree and there should be exactly **one** root node.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
create unique index on simple21_page (parent_id) where parent_id is null;
```

Is this possible with an constraint or unique index, or is a trigger needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there. To get a singleton, you need a unique constraint on a constant value:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON simple21_page ((1)) WHERE parent_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to enforce this kind of uniqueness is usage of `COALESCE` and index on expression:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON simple21_page(COALESCE(parent_id, -1));
```

The value provided as substitute should be out of scope of permitted values.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b219b015c9fde6269843e9ce7b73ade0)**

```
 INSERT INTO simple21_page VALUES (1, 'a', 'text', NULL);
 -- success

 INSERT INTO simple21_page VALUES (2, 'b', 'text', NULL);
 -- ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "simple21_page_coalesce_idx"
```